# ValueError: Image size of 154660x122 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction. I am trying to make timeline and getting error

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, timeline

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(1, 1), constrained_layout=True)
_ = ax.set_ylim(-2, 1.75)
_ = ax.set_xlim("1989", "2021")
_ = ax.axhline(0, xmin=0.05, xmax=0.50, c='deeppink', zorder=1)
 
_ = ax.scatter(dates, np.zeros(len(dates)), s=120, c='palevioletred', zorder=2)
_ = ax.scatter(dates, np.zeros(len(dates)), s=30, c='darkmagenta', zorder=3)

label_offsets = np.zeros(len(dates))
label_offsets[::2] = 0.25
label_offsets[1::2] = -0.4
for i, (l, d) in enumerate(zip(names, dates)):
    _ = ax.text(d, label_offsets[i], l, ha='center', fontfamily='serif', fontweight='bold', color='royalblue',fontsize=8)
```

I want labels to show up but it shows value error.

```
UserWarning: constrained_layout not applied because axes sizes collapsed to zero.  Try making figure larger or axes decorations smaller.
  fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
```

It says value error i have tried changing dimensions but result is same

Comment: Please cite the documentation URL that you are relying on. The given constraints do not appear to be feasible. What part of the diagnostic message was unclear? When I execute `$ expr 154660 - 65536` on my system I obtain `89124`, a positive number. What value appears on your system? When you simplify your program by commenting portions out, which is the offending line that triggers the error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide a [mre] including sample data. What's the type, length and content of ```names``` and ```dates```?